# Add ipSecurity section to web.config on runtime

Tags: web-config

I've been trying to add a new section to web.config *system.webServer/security/ipSecurity* on runtime but without success. I managed to do it with the ServerManager object in System.Web.Administration but I don't think modifying the server host file will work in a shared web environment (?).
Does anyone has any good tips in how to add the section below to the web.config on runtime?

```
<system.webServer>
 <security>
   <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false" denyAction="Unauthorized">
     <clear />
    <add ipAddress="127.0.0.1" allowed="true" subnetMask="255.255.255.0" />
   </ipSecurity>
 </security>
</system.webServer>
```